# Views custom field handler

Tags: views

I need to create custom views field in my module. Basically it should behave like Node edit/delete field. I started with extending views_handler_field class and I can see and add my new field in views admin.

But when I add my new field to view - it don't display any values (empty). I mean - not just my custom field empty, but the whole view. When I remove my custom field - everything is working fine,
My Code:

```
class views_handler_field_gift_delete extends views_handler_field {

    function render($values) {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding an empty query method to your class, e.g. `public function query() {}`

Comment: Tried that without success